# Communism/communism and Communist/communist

Tags: nouns, adjectives, orthography

I have some doubts regarding capitalizing or not the following words:

- Communism
- Communist

I know that Communism is generally written with capital letter, but sometimes I have this doubt and cannot come up with a plausible solution. For example, in: "During Communism/communism people had to...".

As far as communist is concerned, I am pretty sure that it is usually not capitalized, at least, if it is not part of a name, like "the guidelines of the Communist Party of Something". Is that correct or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for any suggestion you might have!

Comment: I know, I saw it, if I made another question it is because the answers I found there were not 100% satisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

The Associated Press Stylebook specifies that you capitalize "Communist" when you're talking about a specific political party. If you're talking about someone who adheres to the more general political philosophy, then you'd use the lower-case c "communist" and "communism."

Answer (score 0):

Generally, one would only capitalize "communism" or "communist" in instances in which the word is a (or a part of) a proper name. Examples:
"The Fall of Communism resulted in the failed dreams of many communists." 
"The Communist Party believes in the ideals of communism."